# Exist of function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ so that $f_n(x)=f(x+\frac{1}{n})$ not converge.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ a function only and let $f_n(x)=f(x+\frac{1}{n})$.

1. Exist a function $f$ so that for some $a\in\mathbb{R}$ the numerical sequence $f_n(a)$ not converge?

2.Exist a function $f$ so that for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$ the numerical sequence $f_n(a)$ not converge?

I COULD NOT FIND EXAMPLES OF THESE FUNCTIONS.

Comment: What does puntually mean?

Comment: @DanielLittlewood...sorry read converge only

Comment: Number 1 is really easy to find an example of.... Just take any $a$ and define $f(a) = 0, f(a+\frac{1}{n}) = n$ for all $n \ge 1$. And you can define $f$ on the rest of $\mathbb{R}$ however you like.

Comment: Yes, if you are looking at continuous functions for your example you won't find any. You'll have to look at discontinuous ones.

Comment: @Teddy38...you know one function $f$ with in 2?